# Highcharts-ng, making rangeselector appear on load

Tags: angularjs, highcharts-ng

I am using highcharts-ng (https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) and can reproduce this issue with one of the examples linked from the readme. Steps to reproduce:

1. Go here:
   http://pablojim.github.io/highcharts-ng/examples/example.html
2. Scroll down and click the "Highchart/Highstock" button
3. Scroll back up (the chart should be blank) and from the first Series
   heading, select Type: Line. Note the chart will redraw. There should be no Zoom/Date Range options at the top of the chart.
4. Now drag the horizontal scroll bar (Navigator) at the bottom of the chart and note the Zoom / Date Range options appear

How do I make these appear on page load? Rather than waiting for our visitors to interact with the chart.

Comment: Started a Git issue here: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/233, including a hacky workaround.